# WPF DataTemplate Binding Background and Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

Having a DataTemplate for all Crosshair types. This template used in ListBox control. My template have a few lines (crosshairs) and a custom control (DragControl). Later with this custom control, you can drag the crosshair. First of all I'm positioning the control top left corner where the center of the crosshair is. Also trying to bind the Background color of the crosshair. Look like is not affecting it. What can be the problem with this approach?

**DragControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFCrosshairSandbox.Views.DragControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Green">
    <Grid/>
</UserControl>
```

**Crosshair.cs**

```
public class Crosshair : BindableBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _name, value); }
    }

    private Brush _color;
    public Brush Color
    {
        get { return _color; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _color, value); }
    }

    private double _thickness;
    public double Thickness
    {
        get { return _thickness; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _thickness, value); }
    }

    private int _x;
    public int X
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _x, value); }
    }

    private int _y;
    public int Y
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _y, value); }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Crosshair}">
            <Canvas>
                <Line Stroke="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness}"
                              X1="{Binding X}"
                              X2="{Binding X}"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
                <Line Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="20"
                              X1="{Binding X}"
                              X2="{Binding X}"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
                <Line Stroke="{Binding Color}" StrokeThickness="{Binding Thickness}"
                              X1="0"
                              X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                              Y1="{Binding Y}"
                              Y2="{Binding Y}" />
                <Line Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="20"
                              X1="0"
                              X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}"
                              Y1="{Binding Y}"
                              Y2="{Binding Y}" />
                <views:DragControl x:Name="xDragControl" Visibility="Collapsed" Canvas.Left="{Binding X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Y}" Background="{Binding Color}"/>
            </Canvas>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="xDragControl" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="MarkerListBoxStyle">
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="MarkerListBoxItemStyle">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ActualHeight}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding ActualWidth}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Content"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="TargetBackgroundImage" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Source="/Views/image.jpg"/>
            <ListBox 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=TargetBackgroundImage}"
                Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=TargetBackgroundImage}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding CrosshairColletion}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCrosshair}" 
                Style="{StaticResource MarkerListBoxStyle}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MarkerListBoxItemStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: You made the UserControl's Visibility Collapsed.

Comment: But in the DataTrigger when it's selected, it get restored.

Comment: How can it get selected if it is not visible?

Comment: You select the "Line" elements, and the "DragControl" becoming visible, because of the "DataTrigger", <Setter TargetName="xDragControl" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>,

Comment: @Buruhazard: Why do you set the `Template` properties of the `ListBox` and the `ListBoxItem`? What binding are not working as expected?